# Nothing is showing up on my compositing panel

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blend-files, compositing-nodes

I have the nodes turned on and have even added things to the space, anyone have any solutions?[image]

Comment: It is possible that the window is zoomed in to a place where there are no nodes. Move the cursor to the node window, press A (to select all) and press Numpad period (.) to zoom to selected. Alternatively press the Home key.

Comment: please show your blend file